# Why does King James Bible Acts 12:4 say "Easter"?

Tags: acts

King James Bible Acts 12:4

> And when he [Herod] had apprehended him [Peter], he put him in prison, and delivered him to four quaternions of soldiers to keep him; intending after **Easter** to bring him forth to the people.

New King James Version

> So when he had arrested him, he put him in prison, and delivered him to four squads of soldiers to keep him, intending to bring him before the people after **Passover**.

Why is there this difference in translations of Easter and Passover in the old and new KJV?

Answer (score 13):

In a sense, it's not wrong, but it's perhaps a bit anachronistic.  The actual Greek in that verse says:

> ὃν καὶ πιάσας ἔθετο εἰς φυλακήν, παραδοὺς τέσσαρσιν τετραδίοις στρατιωτῶν φυλάσσειν αὐτόν, βουλόμενος **μετὰ τὸ πάσχα** ἀναγαγεῖν αὐτὸν τῷ λαῷ.

**meta to pascha** means "after Passover", but the same term, Pascha, is used for Easter in most languages.  English and German are peculiar in calling it Easter (or in German, Ostern) rather than using a term derived from Pesach (Hebrew) / Pascha (Greek) for Passover.

If you look at a list of how various languages say Easter ([here's an example](https://www.indifferentlanguages.com/words/easter)), you'll find that many, perhaps most, use a term that comes from Pesach/Pascha.  In addition, even in English many Eastern Orthodox Churches use the term Pascha instead of Easter.

Comment: But "Easter" refers to the Christian holiday, and doesn't refer to the Jewish holiday, which we have the word "Passover" for, as opposed to "Pesach" which refers to both. So then "Easter" is incorrect - unless it originally referred to both, before the word "Passover" came into existence?

Comment: In a bit more detail, Easter appears to have been a pagan West Germanic goddess of spring, who had her own month in their calendar and feast days. It appears that early West Germanic-speaking Christians found it easiest to simply map to the Christian "rebirth" celebration to their own.

Comment: ...this is a little controversial, as Venerable Bede is the only source of this info, but the West Germanic speakers all using a variant of that name can't be coincidental, so it had to come from *somewhere*. Bede's account seems the only one we are likely to get.

Comment: @Nacht The verse in question is from the English Christian New Testament. It isn't outrageously odd to use the English Christian term to describe the period.

Comment: @T.E.D. Yes, it had to come from somewhere, but that doesn't prove it came from where the Venerable Bede says it came from just because he's the only one who advanced a theory about it.

Comment: @Kyralessa - In history that far back you can't really demand "proof" of course. Think more like the sciences' "evidence", and "theories" to explain our evidence. However, from that standpoint we'd really like more evidence than we have. What we're stuck with right now is that Bede's explanation (theory), while not as well supported as one would like, is the only one we have actual evidence for at all.

Comment: ...which is a long-winded way of saying, yeah that may not be 100% what happened, but its the best most likely theory we have right now. Perhaps future finds will clarify things.

Comment: @T.E.D. Let's not get hung up on semantics. Instead of the word "prove", how about this: There is a paucity of evidence for this "pagan West Germanic goddess of spring." It would be foolish to draw any conclusions about Easter/Pascha based on this flimsy evidence. We don't have to accept a poorly-attested theory merely because it's the only one we have. Anyway, as mentioned, some groups avoid the issue by using the transliteration Pascha instead of Easter. Certainly Pascha itself didn't come from a pagan fertility ritual, though I've seen "Internet scholars" assert that.

Answer (score 9):

This is another of the inexplicable inconsistencies of the KJV.  The NKJV has corrected this obvious anomaly.

The Greek word πάσχα (pascha) is uniformly translated "Passover" with the conspicuous exception of this verse in the KJV.  It perpetuates the odd practice of William Tyndale, 1526, who translated "ester" which was copied by Coverdale Bible, 1535, ("Easter"), and the Bishops Bible, 1568, ("Easter").

There is little justification for this translation.  Although the timing of our modern Easter is related to the Passover, they often fall on different dates and so do not correspond exactly.

Answer (score 0):

There are two practices of the Roman Catholic Church, and one British that directly lead to this issue. First, one of the first defining events of the divergence of the roman catholic church was the councils. If memory serves in the first council setting the date of the Passover by calculation from the Roman calendar instead of the biblical counting of the Abib (ripeness of the barley), which was shortly thereafter followed by the removal of the Jews from Judea to make the counting of the Abib impossible.

Second, the practice of missionary adaption or declaring that all or part of the local unbiblical practices is actually biblical led to the Catholics declaring that the Rites of Estarti were actually Passover leading to confusion and the continuation of egg hunts.

Third, the British empire was not founded on procrastination, but on confidence and promptness. Unfortunately, confidence and promptness are not always virtues for a translator, so since "everyone" knew Easter was the English word for Passover, no-one checked.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at verse 3, you'll see that Peter was arrested during the days of unleavened bread - in other words, during the seven days *after* Passover. So how could Herod intend to release him after a feast that had already passed?

The modern explanation is that "Passover" in verse 4 refers to both Passover and the feast of unleavened bread, taken as a single festival; but, since "Pascha" in Greek is also the Greek word for Easter (the celebration of Christ's resurrection), and Easter logically comes after Passover in the calendar, the early English translators of the Bible assumed this must be an early occurrence of that meaning instead.

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [Tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it may be more appropriate to say something else to indicate the resurrection rather than Passover. Jesus did say, I give you a new covenant fulfilling the prophecy in Jeremiah 31:31-33

> <sup>**31**</sup> The days are coming,” declares the Lord, “when I will make a new covenant with the people of Israel and with the people of Judah.
> <sup>**32**</sup> It will not be like the covenant I made with their ancestors when I took them by the hand to lead them out of Egypt, because they broke my covenant, though I was a husband to them,” declares the Lord. <sup>**33**</sup> “This is the covenant I will make with the people of Israel after that time,” declares the Lord. “I will put my law in their minds and write it on their hearts.

Answer (score -1):

"Its simply because Herod was a PAGAN... and the verse is referencing Easter, a PAGAN festive of fertility that HEROD intends to takes part in! Simple context is lost here. KJV CORRECTLY translates."

The answer above is spot-on.

This is no doubt the reason the KJV Translators used the term Easter.  The NT translates the Greek word for "pascha" as "passover" 28 out of 29 times.  This is the only time there is a deviation in this practice, why?

1. Jesus, for the Christian, is our Passover.  Since the true Passover event was completed any so-called celebration of the event by non-believers (Herod and the Non-believing Jews) only served to highlight the pagan-ness of this particular mention.
2. Secondly, the Pagan celebration of Easter occuring at the same time as this non-believing celebration of Passover, simply highlights the Pagan-ness of the celebration.
3. There are only two mentions of this word for passover after Acts 12:4... in both cases the reference is not to the actual passover event but speaks to the fact that Jesus is our Passover (1Cor5:7) and the other reference is simply stating the historical fact of Moses keeping the Passover (Hebrews 11:28).
4. The obvious reason the KJV used "Easter" to translate "pascha" here is to show that this event was NOT a true passover celebration (Jesus was the fulfilment of the Passover Lamb).  By translating "pascha" as "Easter" (also not a Christian celebration) highlights perfectly this non-believer-pagan celebration and forever distinguishes this mention as being completely different from the other 28 times "pascha" is used.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).